# When is a OWF practically insecure?

Tags: one-way-function

Let's say we got a one way function (OWF). Such a function takes 512-bit input and gives 256-bit output. And let's say we can easly invert some specific inputs. There is exactly $2^{256}$ such blocks which can be easily invert. It is still very small number if we consider $2^{512}$ possible inputs. And as wikipedia wrote: one-way function is a function that is easy to compute on every input, but hard to invert given the image of a **random** input. So there is practically no chance that we will draw such input.

My question is - is it still secure function or should we consider such a function as broken?

Comment: As a OWF it would technically still be secure, you'd just have to ensure to only ever feed it random data. And we could use the usual theoretical constructions to build more sophisticated primitives (like PRFs) from that.